# Must pause Access 2016 VBA to avoid Excel fatal error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am migrating from Access 2010/Windows 7 to Access 2016/Windows 10. I read data from my SQL Server database into an Excel template, save the completed spreadsheet, and then mail it to sundry recipients via CDO. This has worked fine for years in Access 2010/Windows 7.

In Access 2016/Windows 10 however I initially constantly got an "Excel has stopped working" message; the Access code had stopped at apparently random places prior to saving the spreadsheet. If I set a breakpoint and stepped through the code everything worked fine. I then discovered that if I paused the code for 500 msec (as shown in abbreviated code below) everything worked (but not with a pause of 100 msec). Although it is now working, this is not a very satisfactory solution; is there a better one?

```
Dim Temp_rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Set ObjXL = New Excel.Application
ObjXL.Visible = False
Set ObjWkb = ObjXL.Workbooks.Open("\\xxx.xxx.xxx\xxxxa\xx\xxxxxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxxxx\Template.xlsm")
Set ObjSht = ObjWkb.Worksheets("Audit")
ObjSht.Activate
ObjSht.Unprotect ("xxxxxxxx")

'Quite a lot of reading data from various recordsets
mod_OpenMyRecordset Temp_rs, SomeRecordSet
ObjSht.Cells(6, 4) = "Toezegging" & Str(Temp_rs!tzNummer_i)
...etc etc etc

Sleep (500) 'Wait for 0.5 second (necessary for Windows 10!)

ObjSht.Cells(7, 1).Value = "             " & SomeValue
ObjSht.Cells(8, 1).Value = "             " & SomeValue
ObjSht.Cells(9, 1).Value = "             " & SomeValue

ObjSht.PageSetup.RightFooter = "Pagina &P van &N"
ObjSht.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
ObjWkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = True
ObjSht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
ObjSht.Protect ("xxxxxxxx")
MyPath = "\\xxx.xxx.xxx\xxxxa\xx\xxxxxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxx" & Trim(ObjSht.Cells(9, 1).Value) & ".xlsm"

ObjWkb.SaveAs MyPath
ObjWkb.Close

Set ObjSht = Nothing
Set ObjWkb = Nothing
ObjXL.Quit
Set ObjXL = Nothing

Dim objMessage As Object, objBodyPart As Object
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objBodyPart = objMessage.BodyPart
objBodyPart.Charset = "UTF-8"
Set MyObjMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.addAttachment MyPath
objMessage.From = SomeValue
objMessage.Subject = SomeValue
objMessage.To = SomeValue
objMessage.Textbody = SomeValue
objMessage.BCC = SomeValue
With objMessage
  .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
  .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = pubMailServer
  .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
  .Configuration.Fields.Update
  .Send
End With
```

Comment: Create a Range (or several) where you fill in data instead of calling `ObjSht.Cells()` that many times.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to narrow down the potential source of the problem:
1- the code looks good and obviously working before so it is unlikely to be an issue with the code logic
2- I move quite a lot of data in and out of Access to Excel all the time and never have your issue so I also doubt its the size or amount of data you are moving (correct me if I am wrong and its like 500,000 rows x 150 tabs...)
3- I have found that creating additional MSO applications can cause the fatal/catastrophic errors; is there any reason you create a new excel application instead of just a new workbook? Or are you running this in Access, in which case never mind...
4- Your code:

```
ObjSht.Cells(6, 4) = "Toezegging" & Str(Temp_rs!tzNummer_i)
...etc etc etc
```

Is slightly concerning because you are writing directly to ranges one by one for what seems like a large number of data... this is extremely ineffiecient and depending on how it was written could drain the system memory and cause errors- what exactly are you doing with this section of code?

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode

Comment: 1. yes, and in other places in the same application I use the same logic to fill and send other spreadsheets, and they seem to work ok

Comment: 2: Actually only four more cells to fill, although this involves quite a bit of SQL Server manipulation. 3: Yes in Access. 4: OK, but only filling about 10 cells in total.

Comment: @PeterBeresford , I see- that feedback is helpful but has left me somewhat miffed! Where does the code breakdown the most? Hoping the distribution of where the code breaks might give us a clue... I see you have the pause in there now right after your heavy SQL Servcer manipulation, is that where it breaks down the most? If so then perhaps that block prior should be looked at further..

Comment: Acess has generally got as far as one of the ObjSht. statement just above "MyPath ="; it varies from time to time. If I put the block above the SQL Server activity I still get the fatal error. I haven't tested moving it statement by statement (I did't really think that would be usefull)